# "starting on a good foot" or "footing"?

Tags: phrase-choice, frequency

I've often heard the expression "starting sth on a good *footing*". But googling around it seems that "starting on a good *foot*" is much more common, Ludwig doesn't even have an occurrence for "footing", just for "foot" https://ludwig.guru/s/start+on+a+good+footing

Are both expressions correct/idiomatic? Is using one more common than the other? For example: "starting the year on a good foot" Vs. "footing"?

Comment: A more common expression, I believe, is to *start out on the right foot* or to *start on the right foot.* Regrettably, Google's gram has a five-word limit, so I cannot give a more definitive answer.

Comment: [*On a good footing* is much more common than *on a good foot*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+a+good+foot%2Con+a+good+footing&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)  I like Ludwig, but I don't think it is a good tool for telling which version of a phrase is more common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are two different idioms.

'Footing' literally refers to the *grip* that your foot has on the ground. Poor footing can mean you don't have a grip on the ground, could slip and fall over. In a metaphorical context, saying something has started with a '*good footing*' it is a lot like saying it has a *good foundation*; that it has a solid starting point and won't fail from the outset.

The idiom '*starting with the right foot*' is similar, but refers more to an initial decision or first action. For example, if two people "*start off on the right foot*" it means the right things were said and done to form an immediate friendship or partnership. A similar expression, '*put (one's) best foot forward*', means to give your best to something.

The two idioms could be interchangeable in some contexts as they both imply a good start. Arguably the 'footing' that you start with could be something that was already there and not the direct result of a decision or action, although choosing it as a starting place could be.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with ***start on a good footing*** - which according to Google NGrams has little currency anyway (and the ***foot*** version has *no* currency). But as pointed out elsewhere, your ***footing*** refers to the stability of (real or metaphorical) ground underfoot, which is relevant to *maintaining one's current position* rather than *moving*.

The idiom I'm familiar in this area is [***put your best foot forward***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put%20one%27s%20best%20foot%20forward) - variously defined as (US) *to behave very well in order to gain someone's approval* or (UK) *to try as hard as possible to do something difficult.* Here's [the relevant usage chart...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=start%20on%20a%20good%20footing%2Cstart%20on%20a%20good%20foot%2Cput%20your%20best%20foot%20forward&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

[image]